# アップロードファイルが確認画面へのPOST後消えてしまう

Tags: python, django

ファイルアップロードを伴うフォームの作成において、サーバサイド側でのバリデーション後に確認画面での表示をしようとしています。
入力された内容は{{ form.hidden }}で確認画面へ渡しているのですが、その際に、アップロードしたファイルが消えてしまいます。
こちらについて対応方法をご教示いただきたく思います。

・forms.py

```
class SampleForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.Field(
    label='画像のアップロード',
    widget = forms.FileInput())
```

・views.py

```
def form(request):
    form = SampletForm
    return render(request, 'apps/form.html', {"form":form},)

def confirm(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            return render(request,
                'forms/contact.html',
               {"form":form},
            )

def send_email(request):
    # メール送信の処理
```

・form.html

```
<form action="{% url 'apps:confirm'%}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form.image.label }} {{ form.image }}
    <button type="submit">入力内容を確認する</button>
</form>
```

・confirm.html

```
{{ form.image.label }} {{ form.image.value }}
<form action="{% url 'apps:send_email'%}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form.hidden }}
    <button type="submit">送信する</button>
</form>
```

なお、confirm.htmlではアップロードしたファイル名は見える状態です。
submitしメールを送信しても、何も添付されない状態でメールが送信されます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ファイルはPOSTされた時点で一時的に保存（どこかのディレクトリにファイル保存するか、Djangoのcacheに入れるか）しておく必要があります。
確認画面からOKで進むときに、そのキャッシュから取り出して正規の場所に置く感じです。ただしいファイルを取り出せるように一時的なキーを生成して関連づけておくとよいです。

例: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630928/prompt-a-confirmation-page-for-a-form-with-fileinput-field-in-django

実装が面倒な場合は https://github.com/odoku/django-formpreview のように提供されているコードを利用するのもありかと思います。